# Как при клике на блок вытащить содержимое?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oracle

Как при клике div вытащить содержимое ?
Все данные хранятся в БД. 
Есть На левом блоке проекте! у каждого проекта есть вопросы и ответы(cистема тестирования)
как вот при клике на проект вытащить эти данные ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Расскажите как Вы пытались решить проблему. Укажите на чем написана серверная часть сайта.

Comment: определитесь. если вам динамически тянуть данные из базы? тогда используйте ajax.
данные уже прогруженны и тогда обробатывайте js.

Comment: серверная часть написано на PHP. решил с помощью Jquery. AJAX

Answer (score 1):

В свойстве он `onClick` вызови функцию которая будет вытаскивать данные. Их можно вытащить при помощи JQuery, например вытащим текст блока у которого есть класс `filedClass`:

```
$(".filedClass").text();
```

Так же можно и узнавать значения атрибутов